# I'm new to Trig and don't understand.....

Tags: trigonometry, education

I do not understand how to solve this question. I have searched many websites and have not found any information on how to do it.

Find the values for $\theta$ that make each statement true

$$\sin(\theta)=\cos(25^{\circ})$$

Comment: On what interval?

Comment: Degrees or radians? What have you tried or thought about so far?

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a **trigonometric identity**.

In the first quadrant, there is the identity

$$\sin\theta  = \cos(90-\theta)$$

Treat $\theta$ like a variable, and solve.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $\space x=90°- \alpha, \space$ we have:

$$\cos \alpha = \sin x = \sin (90°- \alpha).$$

Answer (score 0):

$sin(\theta)=cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$ and thus we have that

$cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=cos(25) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta=2n\pi\pm 25$

(you can check that these are the only solutions of the equation)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $$\cos (x) = \sin (90°-x)$$
$$\cos 25° = \ ?$$